# Simple class-oriented Tic Tac Toe game in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, tic-tac-toe

This is the code for my Tic Tac Toe game. The player functions are coded in the class `tictactoe` and the rest of the functions, which include checking the board for completion, are global functions. Any tips, advice, or even corrections you guys have, please feel free to share them. I am almost brand-new to programming and I am very open to criticism. I want to learn as much as I can because I'm hoping to become a computer programmer in the future.

Do you agree that the references in `bool isGameover()` to `arr[]` should be deleted?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int game_start();
void instructions();
bool isGameover(char (&arr)[3][3]);
char d = '-';

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::string(d, 30);
  std::cout << "1. Play\n2. Instructions\n3. Exit";
  std::cout << std::string(d, 30);
  std::cout << std::endl;

  int input;

  std::cin >> input;

  switch(input){
    case 1:
      game_start();
      break;
    case 2:
      instructions();
      break;
    case 3:
      return 0;
      break;
    default:
      std::cout << "You didnt enter a valid option. Exiting the program. ";
      return 0;
   } 

}

class tictactoe
{
  public:
      int play(char (&arry)[3][3], const int x, const int y);
      void update(const char arr[3][3]);
      std::string name;
      char symbol;
};

int tictactoe::play(char (&arry)[3][3], const int x, const int y)
{

   if (arry[x][y] = d)
   {
        arry[x][y] = symbol;
        return 1;
   }
   else
   { 
        return 0;
   } 
}

bool isGameover(char (&arr)[3][3])
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
     for (int j = 0; i < 3; j++)
     {
       if ( (&arr)[i][j] == (&arr)[i][j+1] && (&arr)[i][j] == (&arr)   [i][j+2] ||
            (&arr)[i][j] == (&arr)[i+1][j] && (&arr)[i][j] == (&arr)[i+2][j] ||
            (&arr)[0][0] == (&arr)[1][1] && (&arr)[0][0] == (&arr)[2][2] ||
            (&arr)[0][2] == (&arr)[1][1] && (&arr)[0][2] == (&arr)[0][2])
       {
         if (arr[i][j] == 'X' || arr[i][j] == 'O') /// makes sure that the Bool doesnt return "true" if there are three empty spaces in a row.
         {
           return true;
         }
         else
         {
           return false;
         }
       }
       else
       {
         return false;
       }
     }
 }
}

void tictactoe::update(const char arr[3][3])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
      std::cout << arr[i][j];
     }
  }
}

int game_start()
{
  std::string uinput;

  std::cout << "Player one name: ";
  std::cin >> uinput;
  tictactoe Player1;
  Player1.name = uinput;
  Player1.symbol = 'X';
  std::cout << "Player two name: ";
  std::cin >> uinput;
  tictactoe Player2;
  Player2.name = uinput;
  Player2.symbol = 'O';
  int turn = 1;
  char board[3][3] = {d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d};

  while (!isGameover(board)) ///main game loop
  {
    while (turn == 1)
    {
      Player1.update(board);
      std::cout << "Where would you like to move:  ";
      std::cin >> uinput;
      uinput.erase(uinput.find("("));/// gets rid of the symbols in a user's input
      uinput.erase(uinput.find(","));/// so it can be used in the play() function
      uinput.erase(uinput.find(")"));///
      if (!(Player1.play(board, uinput[0], uinput[1])))///checks to   make sure the move is valid
      {
        std::cout << "Move failed. Resetting...\n";
        continue;
      }
      else
      {
        turn = 2;
      }
    } 
    while (turn == 2)
    {
        Player2.update(board);
        std::cout << "It is your turn " << Player2.name << ". Where would you like to move: ";
        std::cin >> uinput;
        uinput.erase(uinput.find("("));
        uinput.erase(uinput.find(","));
        uinput.erase(uinput.find(")"));
        if (!(Player2.play(board, uinput[0], uinput[1])))
        {
            std::cout << "Move failed. Resetting...\n";
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            turn = 1;
        }
    }
  }
  if (isGameover(board))
  {
    if (turn == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Congratulations, " << Player1.name << ". You win!";
    }
    if (turn == 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Congratulations, " << Player2.name << ". You win!";
    }
  }
}

void instructions()
{
    std::cout << "To make a move, type the coordinates of the location on the board you would like to move.";
    std::cout << "Ex: typing ""(0,0)"" without the parenthesis would make a move in the top left square of the board.";
    std::cout << "The board is ordered the same way one would order a 3x3 matrix.";
    std::cout << "To play the game, type 1. To exit, type 2." <<     std::endl;
    int usr;
    std::cin >> usr;
    switch(usr)
    {
        case 1:
            game_start();
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- `if (arry[x][y] = d)` is most likely a typo. You probably meant

  ```
  if (arry[x][y] == d)
  ```
- The condition

  ```
  (&arr)[0][0] == (&arr)[1][1] && (&arr)[0][0] == (&arr)[2][2]
  ```

  does not depend on neither `i` nor `j`. There is no point of testing it 9 times.
- More important, other tests are plain wrong. The code attempts to access elements like `(&arr)[2][4]`, which is certainly not what you want. The only reason you are not getting undefined behaviour is that this code is *never executed*: `isGameover` always returns from the very first iteration.
- An idiom

  ```
  if (condition) {
      return true;
  } else {
      return false;
  }
  ```

  is synonymous to much simpler

  ```
  return condition;
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am going to really tweak the isGameover bool to get it functioning. I'm glad you pointed those errors out; I had a feeling there would be several in that bool.